# AKS Ingress Nginx external IP unreachable

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I m using helm charts to deploy an app in Azure Kubernetes Service with Ingress-nginx
My helm charts used to work fine last month, but when I created something new with my charts, the public IP of my ingress nginx is not working anymore.

```
 PS C:\Zetaris\HelmDeployment> kubectl get ingress -n zetaris
 NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS                             ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
 xx-gui-nginx           <none>   uisaas.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx             20.167.72.8   80, 443   53m
 xx-rest-nginx          <none>   restsaas.xxxxx                    20.167.72.8   80, 443   55m
```

Here is my yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lightning-gui-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-enterprise
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "server: hide";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: DENY";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1";
      more_set_headers "referrer-policy: no-referrer";
      more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'";
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.ingress.guiurl }}
      secretName: tls-secret-gui
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.ingress.guiurl }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: xx-gui-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xx-gui-svc
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9001
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.deployment.name }}
```

I can reach my app on port 9001 if I port-forward directly my pod.
The error is coming from the IP:
telnet 20.167.72.8 80

```
Connecting To 20.167.72.8...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

As far as i know, there no IP restrictions or firewalls in AKS.
Do you have any idea on why would my ingress IP would not be reachable on internet?

Tried to create another app with same helm chart, uninstall and reinstall ingress service, public IP is never reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found the issue, needed to add:

```
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz"
```

When creating the `ingress-nginx`